# Gem Install Rails Zlib.so Load Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wamp

Trying to install Ruby alongside a Wamp Server so I can program in Rails. When I "gem install rails" in CMD, I get the following error:

> C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package.rb:10:in 'require': 126: The specified module could not be found.   - C:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mswin32/zlib.so (Load Error)

I've checked and the zlib.so is definitely there. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need the zlib DLL file.  You can [download it from here](http://www.zlib.net/) and copy it into the same folder as that zlib.so file as `zlib.dll`.  It may be called `zlib1.dll` in the download, and there may already be a `zlib1.dll` on your machine that you need to rename to `zlib.dll`

Comment: Can't find the dll in there, and it says it's looking for the .so which is there. Not sure if that helps

Comment: It's been a while since I've had to work with installing gems on Windows, but usually, I think zlib.so is the Ruby library for ZLIB, which tries to load symbols from the DLL file.  If the DLL file is missing, then the .so will not load, giving you this error.

Comment: Where does the dll need to go?

Comment: I'd try the same folder as zlib.so, but you may also try `C:\Windows\system32`

Comment: The last suggestion solved it, though we decided to switch back to CakePHP